# Main Stored Procedure to Execute another Proc depending on Input and output in a CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two procedures which basically give an Table output. I have the third Procedure which basically calls these two procedures and gives the output in an csv file format.

Can anyone help me in building this the right way. Below is something I am trying to do:

Each of the two Procedures gives out an output with like around 100k rows, I want to capture that and want to give the output here from the Main procedure in a csv file.(Please let me know if you need more info)

```
Create PROC MAIN
   @InputParam int
  AS
 Begin
 Set NOCOUNT ON; 

 BEGIN TRY
 IF @InputParam not in (1,2)
  BEGIN
    Print 'Error Message'
  END
  Else
   begin
   IF @InputParam=1 
     BEGIN
      Exec StoredProc1
      Print 'Stored Procedure StoredProc1 ended at '+Convert(Varchar(25),GETDATE(),21);
     End 
    Else 
      Begin 
      Print 'StoredProc1 does not exist'
      END

    IF @InputParam=2 
     BEGIN
      Exec StoredProc2
      Print 'Stored Procedure StoredProc2 ended at '+Convert(Varchar(25),GETDATE(),21);
     End 
    Else 
     BEGIN 
      Print 'StoredProc2 does not exist'
     END  
  END   -- This is END for ELSE loop

   END TRY

   Begin Catch
     Print 'Input Validation Catch Block with # '+ Convert(Varchar(5),ERROR_NUMBER())+'      Msg: '+ERROR_MESSAGE();

   End Catch
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to try is to declare a table vairable in your main stored procedure. This table needs to match the output from the sub procedures exactly.  The syntax is:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(
  Filed1 INT,
  Field2 VARCHAR(100),
  etc
)
```

Then you can execute your sub stored procedure and insert into the table you defined, like this:

```
INSERT INTO @Temp
EXEC StoredProc1
```

And finally, select from the @Temp

```
SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

You will obviously need to fit your exact requirements into this, but it should assist I hope

You cannot output to a CSV directly from a Stored Procedure without some form of code, so that really depends what you are developing with (ie what will call the stored procedure).  You could perhaps build a SQL Job to output to CSV.